# Looking for a reference MsBuild configuration on a large project

Tags: msbuild

I've been struggling with how to best organize my msbuild project files.  At one time is was all in one file.  Then I split it up into multiple files.

But I want to be able to run 1 master project file that imports everything and builds them with dependencies.  Or be able to build a project independently and not have it worry about not being able to find the task in the "dependsontargets" attribute.

So I was wondering if anybody knew of a good reference for me to see how I should be organizing my projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not earth shattering, but there are a [series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd419659.aspx) of [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dvdarchive/dd483291.aspx) in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163589.aspx).